# Parse text file into nested data structure

Tags: perl, data-structures

This is my text file:

```
animal, cola, husband, 36 
animal, wilma, wife, 31
animal, pebbles, kid, 4
brutal, george, husband, 41
brutal, jane, wife, 39
brutal, elroy, kid, 9
cosa, homer, husband, 34
cosa, marge, wife, 37
cosa, bart, kid, 11
```

And this is the data structure I want:

```
%HASH = (
    animal  => [
        { name => "cola",    role => "husband", age  => 36, },
        { name => "wilma",   role => "wife",    age  => 31, },
        { name => "pebbles", role => "kid",     age  =>  4, },
    ],
    brutal  => [
        { name => "george",  role => "husband", age  => 41, },
        { name => "jane",    role => "wife",    age  => 39, },
        { name => "elroy",   role => "kid",     age  =>  9, },
    ],
    cosa  => [
        { name => "homer", role => "husband", age => 34, },
        { name => "marge", role => "wife",    age => 37, },
        { name => "bart",  role => "kid",     age => 11, },
    ],
);
```

I have some pieces of code, but I can't assemble them into a coherent script. I want only for someone to help me to define this structure and to understand it.

Comment: Does the input file actually have indentations of varying lengths and blank lines separating the data?

Comment: Is the input file a CSV? If so, don't parse it yourself. Use `Text::CSV` instead. https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV

Answer (score 2):

1. Parse each line into a hash.
2. Remove the key column from the hash.
3. Push the hash onto an array based on the key column.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
my @columns = qw(category name role age);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my %temp;
    @temp{@columns} = split(/\s*,\s*/);

    my $key = delete($temp{category});
    push(@{$hash{$key}}, \%temp);
}

print Dumper(\%hash);

__DATA__
animal, cola, husband, 36
animal, wilma, wife, 31
animal, pebbles, kid, 4
brutal, george, husband, 41
brutal, jane, wife, 39
brutal, elroy, kid, 9
cosa, homer, husband, 34
cosa, marge, wife, 37
cosa, bart, kid, 11
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'cosa' => [
                      {
                        'name' => 'homer',
                        'age' => '34',
                        'role' => 'husband'
                      },
                      {
                        'name' => 'marge',
                        'age' => '37',
                        'role' => 'wife'
                      },
                      {
                        'name' => 'bart',
                        'age' => '11',
                        'role' => 'kid'
                      }
                    ],
          'brutal' => [
                        {
                          'name' => 'george',
                          'age' => '41',
                          'role' => 'husband'
                        },
                        {
                          'name' => 'jane',
                          'age' => '39',
                          'role' => 'wife'
                        },
                        {
                          'name' => 'elroy',
                          'age' => '9',
                          'role' => 'kid'
                        }
                      ],
          'animal' => [
                        {
                          'name' => 'cola',
                          'age' => '36',
                          'role' => 'husband'
                        },
                        {
                          'name' => 'wilma',
                          'age' => '31',
                          'role' => 'wife'
                        },
                        {
                          'name' => 'pebbles',
                          'age' => '4',
                          'role' => 'kid'
                        }
                      ]
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you show has one critical rule: A value in a hash can only be a scalar.

So to associate a multi-valued variable with a key use the reference to that variable, here arrayref. And if values in that array need be more complex than scalars you again use a reference, here a hashref.<sup>†</sup> So the value for each key is an arrayref whose elements are hashrefs.

Then you need to learn how to access elements deeper in the structure. That isn't very complex either: dereference them at each level and you can then work with them like you would with an array or hash.

All this is in [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), for which one need be clear with [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). A reference is [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

When this is put to use in your problem

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $file = 'data.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my %result;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $name, $role, $age) = split /\s*,\s*/;

    push @{$result{$key}}, 
         { name => $name, role => $role, age => $age };   
}

dd \%result;
```

This prints the correct data structure. I use [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egaas/Data-Dump-1.23/lib/Data/Dump.pm) to see a complex data structure, which need be installed; there is [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) in the core. There are yet others.

The [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) above uses a regex `/\s*,\s*/` for the delimiter, so to split the line by comma optionally surrounded by spaces. The default for the string to split  is [`$_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables).

Note that we don't have to "add a key" or make its arrayref-value ahead of using them, as that's done via *autovivification*. See for example [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8599456/4653379) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45871957/4653379) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401306/4653379).
It is a complex feature that can bite if misused so please read up on it.

---

<sup>†</sup> If we attempt to use array or hash variables for array elements we are really trying to fit a list of values into a single "slot" of an array.  That can't be done of course, and what happens is that they'll get "flattened" – their elements are merged with all other given scalar elements, and that whole aggregate list populates the array

```
my @ary = 1..3;
my %hash = (a => 10, b => 20);
# Most likely an error:
my @all = (5, @ary, %hash, 100);  #--> (5, 1, 2, 3, a, 10, b, 20, 100)
```

where key-value pairs may come in any order since hashes are inherently unordered.

Instead, we take references to arrays and hashes and write

```
my @all = (5, \@ary, \%hash, 100);
```

Since references are scalars they are legit elements of the array and no flattening happens. So  now contents of `@ary` and `%hash` keep their individuality and can be recovered as needed.